# How can I run all junit tests in the project by using console?

Tags: junit

I wanna use junit 3. Is there such functionality to run all tests by using console in junit 3. If not, does junit 4 support it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create a test suite and all the tests that you want to run to this test suite. Run this test suite from console.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different test suites that are relevant to the part of the code you're working on (as stated in the [faq](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#best_4)) and then run them from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Ant to run all your tests from the console, doesn't matter if it's junit 3 or 4. Ant includes a `junit` task specifically for this. See [my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356342/junit-test-suites/2356470#2356470) for a code sample on how to use Ant for this.

Answer (score 0):

With maven this is very simple

```
mvn test
```