# junit test suites

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a script(test.bat) that allows me to launch one java test by command line :
-java -cp() org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package.Class

Now I want to do the same for several java tests ?
how could I do it? should I have to add the byte code for each java test?
could I have an example , please?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ant to run your tests with a single command with the `junit` ant task. Here's an example on how to use it:

```
<target name="runtests" depends="clean,compiletests">           
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.classpath" />                 
            <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
        </classpath>                                
        <formatter type="xml"/>     
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>        
</target>
```

That target uses `batchtest` which is part of the junit ant task. It sets your test classpath so all your tests that contain the *Test*.java pattern in their class name will be included. Check out the [JUnit Task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Answer (score 2):

In JUnit, you can group your tests into a test suite and then run that with a single command.

<strike>Here is a tutorial on [using test suites in JUnit 3](http://clarkware.com/articles/JUnitPrimer.html#testsuite), and</strike> here is an SO post about [same with JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457276/junit4-test-suites). <strike>Moreover, here is a tutorial on [how to use the new features of JUnit 4](http://www.wakaleo.com/public_resources/wjug-junit4.pdf).</strike>

However, if you are practically trying to write a build script in your batch file, I recommend using an existing build system instead, be it [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) or something else.

Comment: peter, could you please send me a useful link to junit doc : how to use @Test,@Beforeclass,... I begin with Junit
thanks

Comment: @lamisse I added a new link, hope it helps.

Comment: @PéterTörök: Your link for test suites un JUnit 3 is broken

Comment: @PéterTörök: Your link for how to use the new features of JUnit 4 is broken too

Comment: @AdrienBe, here is [an apparently rewritten version](http://www.slideshare.net/wakaleo/junit-kung-fu-getting-more-out-of-your-unit-tests), with different title but AFAIR largely the same content.

Answer (score 0):

A convention used in JUnit is to have an AllTests test suite that groups all tests in the project together and have an Ant script or whatever execute the AllTests test suite.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possibilities:

- Use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) (see other answers while I'm typping)
- update your batch to java -cp ... file1 file2 filen
- use something like this:

  ```
  org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(TestClass1.class, ...);
  public class GlobalTest { }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of suites using the JUnit annotation syntax. I describe it in [more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457276/junit4-test-suites/4952225#4952225).